# Set center on Mapbox GL map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, api, mapbox-gl-js, html5

I have a form HTML, e.g. like this:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="#">
        <input class="sidebar__input" type="text" name="lat" id="latitude" />
        <input class="sidebar__input" type="text" name="lng" id="longitude"/>

        <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="onLoadConfigPress(document.getElementById('button').value)" />
</form>
```

Now, I want to pass latitude and longitude value to the **center option** in **Map object**:

```
var map=mapboxgl.Map({
   container: 'map',
   style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
   center: [longit, latit],  <------ **HERE**
   ...
```

when I click on **Submit** button in HTML form.
What API Mapbox I must to use to pass latitude and longitude value to the center option? How to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When submitting your form, you can use your `onLoadConfigPress` function to read the values from the form fields and set the center of the map with [`setCenter`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setcenter):

For example:

```js
// create map with initial center
var map = mapboxgl.Map({
   container: 'map',
   style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
   center: [0, 0]
});

function onLoadConfigPress() {
  // get long and lat 
  var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude').value;
  var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude').value;

  // set center of map
  map.setCenter([longitude, latitude])
}
```

and call the function on submit

```html
<form id="form">
  <input class="sidebar__input" type="text" name="lat" id="latitude" />
  <input class="sidebar__input" type="text" name="lng" id="longitude"/>
  <button type="button" onclick="onLoadConfigPress()">Set center</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ummm ....and how to pass **long** and **lat** to **setCenter** from HTML form?

Comment: hi! Thanks for the comment. I've elaborated on my answer. Hope this works for you.